# Should this snarky answer get flagged?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers

The question asks how to suppress output to stdout when calling a function.

One of the posted answers is to comment out the call to the function, thereby not running the code at all and avoiding the need to suppress any output at all.

Should the answer be flagged? If so, what should it be flagged as?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21379650/901641

Comment: No. Downvote(if you feel that something isn't right), comment the problem, move on. Flagging is when a mod needs to look at. It is an answer, nevertheless. No flags needed here!

Comment: You can always downvote and post underneath saying "I comment out your answer, and now StackOverflow works for me."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed an answer, so **should not** be flagged as *Not an answer*.

You also make an assumption that it was intentionally snarky. This is an old answer from a user who doesn't have the highest skill set and I would assume that English is not this person's first language - so they were quite possibly genuine with the answer, this is how they would have solved it back then.

Because of its low quality the appropriate thing to do is to down vote it if you think it deserves that, and move on. If it accumulates enough down votes then trusted users can vote to delete it (I've already cast a delete vote myself). As mentioned by [Cool Guy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293699/should-this-snarky-answer-get-flagged/293703#comment190444_293699), it doesn't require moderator attention.

**Update:** problem solved - the answer has now been deleted by trusted users.

Answer (score -2):

Flag as NAA, but first be sure to comment to politely explain why pointlessly trolling answers are of no value. Flagging without a clear comment is likely to end in incrementing your declined flag count to no purpose.

This "answer" doesn't really solve the problem in a way that fits the (implicit) prerequisites, so it should be a comment, except that as a comment it's not actually constructive, so it should be deleted accordingly. It simply doesn't belong anywhere on the main site.